# Xcode 5, disabling Storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, xcode5

I don't want to use story boards, i'd much rather use NIB's for UI when necessary, and I particularly don't want to use them for the default templates.

Xcode 5 no longer has the check box to say you don't want to use Storyboards,

can anyone help? It's really annoying...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**STEPS FOR REMOVE STORY BOARD - XCode 5 (EDIT)**

1/ Create an empty project

2/ Add new files with xib for your controller , if it is not added in compiled sources in build phases then add there manually.

4) Change appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions file and add :

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

just like :

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;

     // Override point for customization after application launch.

     TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
     UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:test];
     self.window.rootViewController = nav;

     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

     return YES;
  }
```

**STEPS FOR REMOVE STORY BOARD**

1) Remove Main.storyboard file from your project.

2) Add new files with xib for your controller , if it is not added in compiled sources in build phases then add there manually.

3) Remove Main storyboard file base name from plist.

4) Change appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions file and add :

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

just like :

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;

     // Override point for customization after application launch.

     TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
     UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:test];
     self.window.rootViewController = nav;

     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

     return YES;
}
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234172/xcode-5-without-storyboard-and-arc)

Comment: Awesome, will mark as correct when I can in 7 minutes, do you think I should learn storyboards and accept them, will they be forced by Xcode 6? I think they suck, what do you think? - Like if I want to do a custom UIView with custom elements for a little menu I present in my App a nib is so elegant, I can't do a simple UIView based UI with storyboards can I?

Comment: I'm not using Storyboard and I don't want to use it.
A good discussion of that here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903752/best-pratice-between-storyboard-xib-nib-pure-programming

Comment: @JohnWoods for what you mentioned, I use my Storyboard, then add a View where I want my custom control and change the type to my custom control class type.

Comment: Better create empty project, so you just add Xib file and code, don't need to delete anything

Answer (score 2):

Use this script to get all the shiny, happy glorious goodness of the Xcode 4 templates back: https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/Xcode4templates

You will need a copy of the Xcode 4 .app bundle to use this script.