# Xcode5 and iOS7 - Getting Started

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I recently updated to Xcode5, only to find myself in a totally unfamiliar environment. A lot of the important things I had gotten used in the previous year works differently or just simp[ly don't work at all, starting with the way how I initiate my root viewController in the appDelegate. It used to be something like this:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

With Xcode5 and iOS7, however, this has changed, and I cannot even do the most simplest things. There is simply nothing in the AppDelegate now.

I know it is a very broad question and Sketch Overflow does not like these types of questions, but can someone point me toward a tutorial, or documentation that lists the most important changes in the new Xcode and how to overcome them? I did a search on the Apple Developer website but found nothing. I know it is probably there I am just not finding it.

Sorry for the vague, amateurish question! :(

Comment: I'm using the same sort of way to set the main window and rootviewcontroller in iOS 7 and it works. So I'm guessing you made some other mistake.

Comment: Welcome to **Sketch Overflow** :)

Comment: rcKoenes: I believe you. But how came that when you create a new iOS7 application with the new sdk, the appDelegate is basically empty. At least I don't see any rootViewController declaration in it; yet, the app still launches. That, to me, seems like things don't works quite the same way as they used to.

Comment: [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want using Storyboard with XCode 5 you can follow my explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052696/xcode-5-disabling-storyboards/19052732#19052732) to remove storyboard and start with an empty project with xib files.

There are many differences with XCode 5 but you'll have mostly interface mainly due to the status bar problems. But you can continue to use iOS 6 and 6 on XCode SDK 5.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need that code in XCode 5, thats old way.

Interface Builder is merged in new tool called Storyboard.

There you pull UINavigationController from toolbox and set its `rootViewController` by pulling new UIViewController from toolbox.

You perform this merge by holding right ctrl and clicking in a viewcontrller and pulling the pointer to next view controller. This creates a Segue, which is a new tool for handling creation of view controller and pushing it to view controller stack.